# Commuting supremum and expectation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Suppose to have random variables $X_t \geq 0$ for every $t\in [0,1]$. Suppose also that
$E[X_t] < \infty$ uniformly for every $t \in [0,1]$ (which implies $\sup_{t \in [0,1]} E[X_t] < \infty$). Can I conclude that
$$
E[\sup_{t \in [0,1]} X_t] < \infty ?
$$
Or, more in general, under which conditions can I say that there exists $C > 0$ such that
$$
E[\sup_{t \in [0,1]} X_t] \leq C \sup_{t \in [0,1]} E[X_t] ?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Even worse, it is possible that under your assumptions  $\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}X_t=\infty$ with positive probability. Consider the following example:

Let $X_0\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ and define $$X_t=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{1-t}X_0, & t\in [0,1) \\ 0, & t=1\end{cases}$$
Then clearly $\lim_{t\nearrow 1}X_t=\text{sign}(X_0)\cdot\infty$. 
Therefore $$\mathbb E\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}X_t=\mathbb P[X_0>0]\cdot\mathbb E\bigg[\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}X_t\bigg|X_0>0\bigg]+ \mathbb P[X_0<0]\cdot\mathbb E\bigg[\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}X_t\bigg|X_0<0\bigg]=+\infty$$

Furthermore, an inequality as you describe it, i.e. $\mathbb E\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}X_t\leq C \cdot\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}\mathbb EX_t$, is unlikely to hold for a large class of processes satisfying your conditions. Simply consider a zero-mean process, then such an inequality would imply that $\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}X_t=0$ which together with the condition $\mathbb EX_t=0$ implies $X_t=0$ almost-surely.

Though perhaps an interesting class where similar bounds can be achieved are [Submartingales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)#Submartingales,_supermartingales,_and_relationship_to_harmonic_functions). In particular you may want to take a look at [Doob's Martingale Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality).

Comment: Thank you very much also for the further reading. I have also the assumption that $X_t \geq 0$ for every $t$. This means that the second example is ok for me (since a positive process with mean always zero is expected to be equals to zero almost surely). But you are right, changing a little bit your first example you can obtain something that makes the inequality false.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in reality I'm realising that also the first example you give it is not what I'm searching. Since $X_t$ is always positive, in the case you described both side of the inequality are equals to $+\infty$, which makes the inequality true